# Xamarin forms iOS on orientation changes image goes to corner

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.forms, screen-orientation

I have a custom control for gesture control. I have a xaml with a image inside the control. On android I have the orientation change disabled, but on iOS we distribute for ipad, so orientation change is allowed.

If I enter to the screen in portrait or landscape all goes ok, but if I enter in portrait and then I change the orientation the image, who previously was centered, moves to a corner taking the center as the coords 0,0. Eventually if you change a lot the orientation the image simply goes off.

I tried to remove the gesture control and the image was ok, I also tried to put the control inside a AbsoluteLayout and then it works ok, but the image don't fill the screen.

This is the xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <controls:GestureContainer>
            <controls:GestureContainer.Content>
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage     
                        x:Name="_imageCache"
                        Aspect="AspectFit"
                        DownsampleToViewSize="True"
                        Source="{Binding Image.ImageStream}"/>
             </controls:GestureContainer.Content>
        </controls:GestureContainer>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And this is the GestureContainer Control

```
public class GestureContainer : ContentView
{
    private const double MIN_SCALE = 1;
    private const double MAX_SCALE = 4;
    private double startScale, currentScale;
    private double startX, startY;
    private double xOffset, yOffset;

    public GestureContainer()
    {            
        var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);

        var pan = new PanGestureRecognizer();            
        pan.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pan);

        TapGestureRecognizer tap = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 };
        tap.Tapped += OnTapped;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);

        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
    }

    private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Content.Scale > MIN_SCALE)
        {
            RestoreScaleValues();
        }
        else
        {
            Content.AnchorX = Content.AnchorY = 0.5;
            Content.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);             
        }
    }
    void RestoreScaleValues()
    {
        Content.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        Content.TranslateTo(0.5, 0.5, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);

        currentScale = 1;

        Content.TranslationX = 0.5;
        Content.TranslationY = 0.5;

        xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
        yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
    }

    void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
        {
            startScale = Content.Scale;
            Content.AnchorX = 0;
            Content.AnchorY = 0;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
        {
            // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
            currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
            currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the X pixel coordinate.
            double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
            double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
            double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
            double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
            double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
            double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
            double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
            double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

            // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
            double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
            double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

            // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
            Content.TranslationX = targetX.Clamp(-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
            Content.TranslationY = targetY.Clamp(-Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

            // Apply scale factor.
            Content.Scale = currentScale;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
        {
            // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
            xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
            yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
        }
    }

    void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {          
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                startX = e.TotalX;
                startY = e.TotalY;
                Content.AnchorX = 0;
                Content.AnchorY = 0;
                break;

            case GestureStatus.Running:
                var maxTranslationX = Content.Scale * Content.Width - Content.Width;
                Content.TranslationX = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(-maxTranslationX, xOffset + e.TotalX - startX));

                var maxTranslationY = Content.Scale * Content.Height - Content.Height;
                Content.TranslationY = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(-maxTranslationY, yOffset + e.TotalY - startY));

                break;

            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
                break;                   
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you solved your issues?

Comment: No... Your option was good at first, and thats wat I give you +1, but if I change the anchors the rotation works ok, but the gestures becomes weird

Answer (score 1):

[AnchorX](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.AnchorX/) declares the X component of the transform and the default value is 0.5. Why do you want to set the `GestureContainer`'s `AnchorX` to 0? You can try to remove the code in the construction method.

Since you set it to 0, when you rotate the screen the page will layout its subviews again. Then you will see the `GestureContainer` moves to the corner of the page like (0, 0).

The event `OnMeasure()` will fire when the orientations change, so you can also reset it in this event:

```
protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
{
    Scale = MIN_SCALE;
    Content.TranslationX = Content.TranslationY = 0;
    Content.AnchorX = Content.AnchorY = 0.5;
    return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
}
```